# Future throw exception handle outside from origin future

Tags: dart, dart-async

i am trying to understand, how dart future exception works. I read a very good article about it [link](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/futures-and-error-handling/). But when i have nested future and the first of them throw an error, how can i handle this error on the second future.

To clarify, what i mean look at the following sample.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {

  var fur1 = new Future<int>(() => 45);
  fur1.then((value) {
    throw new StateError('Hello error');
  });

  var fur2 = new Future<int>(() => 24);
  fur2.then((value) {
    fur1.then((value1) {
      print(value1);
    });
    print(value);
  }).catchError((err) => print(err));
}
```

In the fur1, i throw an exception and expected to catch the error in the fur2, but the compiler show message

> Unhandled exception: Bad state: Hello error

It is possible to handle nested error in future? I know, i could use here the completer class, maybe it would be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you actually try to accomplish.

but for me it works this way

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {

  var fur1 = new Future<int>(() => 45);
//  fur1.then((value) {
//    throw new StateError('Hello error');
//  });

  var fur2 = new Future<int>(() => 24);
  fur2.then((value) {
    var x = fur1.then((value1) {
      print(value1);
        throw new StateError('Hello error'); // <= inner exception
      });
      print(value);
      return x; // <= return future
    }).catchError((err) => print('catchError: ${err}'));
  }
```

or this way

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {

  var fur1 = new Future<int>(() => 45);
  fur1.then((value) {
    throw new StateError('Hello1 error');
  }).catchError((err) => print('catchError1: ${err}'));

  var fur2 = new Future<int>(() => 24);
  fur2.then((value) {
    var x = fur1.then((value1) {
      print(value1);
      throw new StateError('Hello2 error'); // <= inner exception
    });
    print(value);
    return x; // <= return future
  }).catchError((err) => print('catchError2: ${err}'));
}
```

```
catchError1: Bad state: Hello1 error
24
45
catchError2: Bad state: Hello2 error
```

Comment: that is exactly, what i try to accomplish! Thx so much.

Comment: What makes the original program fail is that the listener on `fur1` is added *after* it has completed with an error. That means that the error is considered unhandled, and it becomes a top-level uncaught error. The listener on `fur1` is added inside the `then` handler of another future, which will trigger at some point in the future, which happens to be after the `fur1` future completed.